# SELinux httpd write access to a directory

Tags: fedora, rhel, apache-httpd, selinux

I am new to SELinux. came from debian. I want to give `httpd` access to a directory.

**SELinux Alert Browser** suggests:

```
# grep httpd /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M mypol
# semodule -i mypol.pp
```

I couldn't understand how does this command work. I don't specify a directory path anywhere. how does it know which directory to allow for httpd ?

Previously I've used grep to extract text from output or file. But here grep is being used on a process. That I didn't get.

Also what is the actual solution. If I want to give httpd write access to a directory ?

Comment: And to answer your other question, audit2allow reads the SELinux log file and writes a policy allowing anything that's been blocked; the directory name will be in the log message. By grepping for httpd you're limiting it a bit, but the method is still more broad than it should be.

Comment: Relevant answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/511929/website-cannot-write-to-files-or-create-directories/582622#582622

Answer (score 18):

Here's how to permanently change the context of a directory:

```
# install semanage if you don't already have it. It'll be one of:
yum install policycoreutils-python
dnf install policycoreutils-python-utils

# give the directory a new default context. The part at the end is a regex.
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/path/to/directory(/.*)?"

# apply the default context to the directory
restorecon -R /path/to/directory
```

Here's some more documentation on the different contexts for httpd:

RHEL 8: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/using_selinux/configuring-selinux-for-applications-and-services-with-non-standard-configurations_using-selinux#customizing-the-selinux-policy-for-the-apache-http-server-in-a-non-standard-configuration_configuring-selinux-for-applications-and-services-with-non-standard-configurations

RHEL 7: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/SELinux_Users_and_Administrators_Guide/sect-Managing_Confined_Services-The_Apache_HTTP_Server-Types.html

RHEL 6: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Managing_Confined_Services/sect-Managing_Confined_Services-The_Apache_HTTP_Server-Types.html

Comment: Perfect!!Worked for me in Fedora 26, policycoreutils-python was already installed by default.

Answer (score 6):

SELinux makes use of extended attributes that can appended to the directory structures on the disk. Think of these as meta data. Access Control Lists (ACLs) being another.

The extended attributes that you need to append to a directory are called contexts and SELinux acts like a traffic cop, making sure that an executable that has certain contexts is allowed to access the filesystem based on these contexts. You can see what's available on the directory using the `-Z` switch to `ls`.

```
$ sudo ls -Z /var/www
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_script_exec_t:s0 cgi-bin
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 html
```

Here you can see that these directories have the context `httpd_sys_script_exec_t:s0` on the `cgi-bin` dir. and the `html` dir. has `httpd_sys_content_t:s0`.

You can add these using the `chcon` command:

```
$ sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_content_t public_html
```

The command you're asking about will simply load the module `mypoll.pp` I do not believe it will grant any permissions to anything, there is likely more messages in the `audit.log` that you're missing with your command, that will tell you in more detail what you need to do to allow access.

I'd encourage you to take some time and familiarize yourself with SELinux. It's confusing at first but is generally straightforward, after spending a little time with it. See the resources below to get you started.

#### References

- [CentOS SELinux Wiki Tutorial](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux)
- [Apache and SELinux](https://beginlinux.com/server_training/web-server/976-apache-and-selinux)
- [Gentoo Hardened SELinux Tutorials](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SELinux/Tutorials)

Comment: Thanks. I'll go through them. But can you tell me for now what I need to do to give write access to this directory ?

Comment: If it's content that you want Apache to read you likely need to add this context to the dir: `chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t <dir>`